# Blur background view after segue

Tags: swift, swift2, uivisualeffectview, uiblureffect

I have two views, one with some information and a button which performs a show segue to another view controller which I will call SVC. I want to add the UIBlurEffect to the UIView on SVC but all I have come across is adding subviews with blur which doesn't help me at all. Any help would be fantastic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to make your SVC as a blur above your first VC. U can do this:

first make the UIView on SVC bgcolor to clearColor [image]

second add UIBlurEffect to the UIView as subview like this [image]

and then make your content in the view in Visual Effect View

Comment: Clearing the colour on SVC makes the background black because of the show segue.

Comment: @needshelp Cant understand what u really want. Use show segue your first VC will move away, so why u need SVC blur.

Comment: I want blur on the SVC. Setting the background colour to clear actually makes the SVC black.

Comment: @needshelp you mean blur SVC and it above another VC? or just in SVC you have a view want blur and the view is  above other view?

Comment: I want the SVC to blur the first vc.

Comment: @needshelp So U cant use show segue , cause it will move the first VC out the screen. Try use present modally and presentation : over full screen; If will really just want use slide animation then you have to write a custom segue see this link http://mathewsanders.com/custom-menu-transitions-in-swift/

Comment: Thanks Rick! Sorry for being confusing!

Comment: @needshelp Happy coding :)